# Can't access a specific variable on this scenario

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why i can't access `that.Friends.name` here (see the code below):

**UPDATE**

**JS**

```
function AClass(_Friends) {
  var that = this;
  this.Friends = _Friends;

  this.doSomething = function() {
    console.log(that.Friends.name); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined 
  };
}

var A = new AClass({ name: 'toto' });
$('button').click(A.doSomething);
```

**HTML**

```
<button>TRY!</button>
```

I use  `var that = this` on the controller of my classes because i could be interesting about calling my methods on callbacks (like in this example), i am not very proud of this, do you have any better way to make it works (maybe it's a good idea te redefined `this` here) ?

Comment: change `var Friends = _Friends;` to `this.Friends = _Friends;`

Comment: Or, better yet, just use `Friends` instead of `that.Friends` -- you already have access to it via closure, no need to make it a property of `that`.

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/droppedonjapan/8SC6u/

Comment: Shouldn't `doSomething = function()` be `this.doSomething = function()`?

Comment: Essentially you had the `this.Friends = _Friends` messup.  Also you need to return an object if you want to use the `A.doSomething()` function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the `var that = this;` pattern; in fact, that's something that Douglas Crockford has used in example code.

Comment: If you want to read more on patterns that would help you figure out how to set up Classes like this in JS, [should check this book out.](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)  It outlines several ways of doing it, along with benefits/ downsides.

Comment: Your code example as it is right now (after a few changes) actually doesn't produce any errors when i try it ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGTj3/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing `doSomething` directly, you're detaching it from the object. jQuery or no jQuery, this would stop working.

However, to *definately* make it stop working (if that makes any sense), jQuery forces the value of `this` to be the element clicked inside a handler *anyway*.

To fix `this` (haha), you simple need to use an anonymous function;

```
$('button').click(function () {
    A.doSomething();
});
```

Now, the value of the anonymous function gets forced to `this`, but we really don't care, as it's the value of the `doSomething()` we're interested in; which, as it's still attached to `A`, and hasn't been forced via `call` or `apply`, it the value we need.

With this, there's no need for `var that = this`; although its a well used JavaScript idiom/ technique, so I wouldn't worry about it myself.

Comment: While useful advice, that doesn't really solve his TypeError.

Comment: @Matt thanks for this usefull tips, but i do use `this` i forgot to mention it in my post, i have updated it sorry about that

Comment: @Ludo: See now. In future, you *really* shouldn't change questions as much as you have done here. You've got about 5 answers and 5 comments, all addressing your question in the various forms its taken over the past 10 minutes

Comment: @Matt Ok thanks, but there is one thing i don't understand, why can we use `var that = this` then declaring a funciton and using `that` into it to refer to the previous value of `this`, and we can't use the same process when a calling a callback, since `that` has been defined before the callback's call, what is the difference?

Comment: The code you've got (or *ended up with* after several iterations) works as it is (http://jsfiddle.net/zGTj3/); even whilst using `var that = this;`. Does that answer your question? If not, I'm not sure I understand... can you expand?

Answer (score 1):

`Friends` is a local variable in an outer scope; you can access it directly without using `that`:

```
console.log(Friends.name);
```